# Change text color to match dynamic background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of my links on hover to match the background which is always changing. Here's a JSFiddle of what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcz7gk72/

Basically, I want the "test@test.com" to match the body background color on hover.

Would appreciate any help. Unless it's really needed, I'd rather not use jQuery and keep this to just Javascript.

```css
body {
    font: 20px monospace;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    animation: pulse 60s infinite normal;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 60s infinite normal;
    -moz-animation: pulse 60s infinite normal;
    -o-animation: pulse 60s infinite normal;
}
a {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    position: relative;
}
a:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 0;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    content: "";
    transition: width 0.4s;
}
a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% { background-color: #f00; }
    25% { background-color: #0f0; }
    50% { background-color: #00f; }
    75% { background-color: #00a; }
    100% { background-color: #0a0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% { background-color: #f00; }
    25% { background-color: #0f0; }
    50% { background-color: #00f; }
    75% { background-color: #00a; }
    100% { background-color: #0a0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0% { background-color: #f00; }
    25% { background-color: #0f0; }
    50% { background-color: #00f; }
    75% { background-color: #00a; }
    100% { background-color: #0a0; }
}
@-o-keyframes pulse {
    0% { background-color: #f00; }
    25% { background-color: #0f0; }
    50% { background-color: #00f; }
    75% { background-color: #00a; }
    100% { background-color: #0a0; }
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a>
```

Comment: What's the actual problem with your code as it is (other than I'd strongly suggest including `position: relative` on the `a` rather than the `a:hover`, if you don't see why just watch the `a::after` pseudo element when you un-hover the `<a>`)? But the only reason the background of the `<a>` (on `:hover`) doesn't show the `background` of the `<body>` is that it's hidden by the pseudo-element, which I assume is deliberate. So please: could you clarify, and explain, the problem you need help with?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the quick response. I simply want on a:hover for the font color of "test@test.com" to be the same as the color of the body background (but this keeps changing).

Comment: I'd say the easiest way to achieve this is to create a keyframe animation for the text-color property, similar to what you've done with the pulse animation.

Comment: @Stef I tried that, it doesn't work because it won't start changing colors until he hovers over the link, So I was thinking maybe setting the text to a transparent to see the color behind.

Comment: Hey Stef, that's a great recommendation but it starts the keyframes timer on hover (so it's not at the same time as the background body color change). Any idea on how to have them be in sync?

Comment: Touché. I hadn't thought of that. I'll play around with it. I'm curious to find a CSS-only solution now as well :)

Comment: Out of curiosity: [this](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a9s76wka/)?

Comment: @Edvard I think javascript will be the way to go, that way the timer could control the colors. I wish I wasn't getting off work so soon, this one looks like fun!

Comment: @DavidThomas out of curiousity, you are right lol!!! put that thing in the answer below!

Comment: David's answer is probably what you're looking for, but an alternative with a bit of different look but that might be acceptable is to just add `opacity: .5;` to `a:after`.

Comment: Can we find a way to prevent the #FF0000 that you initially see on hover with @DavidThomas suggestion? It's so close...

Comment: Yeah, I added a new `a:hover` just as part of my initial 'debugging' efforts. Since removed in the answer I'll post in a moment.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. That's a flawless solution. Great job!

Comment: Can't wait to see David's update that fixes the initial #f00 on hover. This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks so much!

Comment: Haha, upvote for enthusiasm @Edvard. As soon as the answer is posted I'll give him an upvote too. Thanks for giving us a fun challenge :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a new animation to animate the `color` property of the text shown on hover of the `<a>` element, and adding – or changing – `a::after` (or, indeed, the `a:after`) rules.

The changes are included, and explained, in the CSS below:

```css
body {
  font: 20px monospace;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  animation: pulse 60s infinite normal;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 60s infinite normal;
  -moz-animation: pulse 60s infinite normal;
  -o-animation: pulse 60s infinite normal;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
  text-decoration: none;

  /* I added this rule to the
  base 'a' rule, to avoid the
  otherwise ghastly jump
  when un-hovering the <a>: */
  position: relative;
}
a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
a:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;

  /*
    slowed down significantly, to clearly
    show the transition of the text as it
    progresses across the element: */

  transition: width 3s;

  /* 
  Obtaining the text to show from the
  custom data-attribute: */

  content: attr(data-text);

  /*
  To hide the pseudo-element's
  text in the non-hovered state: */

  overflow: hidden;

  /* 
  /linking to the animation: */

  -webkit-animation: textPulse 60s infinite normal;
  -moz-animation: textPulse 60s infinite normal;
  -o-animation: textPulse 60s infinite normal;
  animation: textPulse 60s infinite normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #0a0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #0a0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #0a0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #0a0;
  }
}
@keyframes textPulse {
  0% {
    color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    color: #0a0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes textPulse {
  0% {
    color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    color: #0a0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes textPulse {
  0% {
    color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    color: #0a0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes textPulse {
  0% {
    color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    color: #0a0;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:test@test.com" data-text="test@test.com">test@test.com</a>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a9s76wka/1/) for experimentation and development.

Unfortunately the above solution does require you to ensure that the `data-text` attribute exists, and is filled with the appropriate text; with that in mind – and despite your preference to not rely upon JavaScript – I'd like to post another snippet that employs a JavaScript function to appropriately fill set, and fill, the `data-text` attribute on the relevant elements:

```
// using the Immediately-Invoked Function Expression ('IIFE')
// syntax to invoke the wrapped anonymous function without
// having to call it elsewhere:
(function() {
  // getting all the elements, using document.querySelectorAll(),
  // with the (atrociously long, but explanatory) class-name of
  // 'showBodyBackgroundColoredTextOnHover' (by all means, please,
  // choose a shorter class-name):
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.showBodyBackgroundColoredTextOnHover');

  // Using Function.prototype.call() to apply an Array
  // method, Array.prototype.forEach(), on the
  // Array-like NodeList returnd by querySelectorAll():
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
    // the first argument of forEach() is the array-element
    // of the Array over which we're currently iterating:

    // using the HTMLElement.dataset to create the
    // 'data-text' attribute/property value:
    el.dataset.text = el.textContent;
  });
})();
```

```js
(function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.showBodyBackgroundColoredTextOnHover');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
    el.dataset.text = el.textContent.trim();
  });
})();
```

```css
body {
  font: 20px monospace;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  animation: pulse 60s infinite normal;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 60s infinite normal;
  -moz-animation: pulse 60s infinite normal;
  -o-animation: pulse 60s infinite normal;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* I added this rule to the
  base 'a' rule, to avoid the
  otherwise ghastly jump
  when un-hovering the <a>: */
  position: relative;
}
a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
a:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  /*
    slowed down significantly, to clearly
    show the transition of the text as it
    progresses across the element: */
  transition: width 3s;
  /* 
  Obtaining the text to show from the
  custom data-attribute: */
  content: attr(data-text);
  /*
  To hide the pseudo-element's
  text in the non-hovered state: */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* 
  /linking to the animation: */
  -webkit-animation: textPulse 60s infinite normal;
  -moz-animation: textPulse 60s infinite normal;
  -o-animation: textPulse 60s infinite normal;
  animation: textPulse 60s infinite normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #0a0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #0a0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #0a0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #0a0;
  }
}
@keyframes textPulse {
  0% {
    color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    color: #0a0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes textPulse {
  0% {
    color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    color: #0a0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes textPulse {
  0% {
    color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    color: #0a0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes textPulse {
  0% {
    color: #f00;
  }
  25% {
    color: #0f0;
  }
  50% {
    color: #00f;
  }
  75% {
    color: #00a;
  }
  100% {
    color: #0a0;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:test@test.com" class="showBodyBackgroundColoredTextOnHover">test@test.com</a>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a9s76wka/3/) for experimentation and development.

Comment: As I stated previously, flawless solution. Great job!

Comment: I'm glad to have helped, and you are very welcome! :)

Comment: Awesome! Do you know why the position of the text on hover is slightly different from the default placement?

Comment: @Edvard: yes; that's the one kink I couldn't quite solve in the demos. I thought I'd more or less got it, though. If you can improve it you'd be most welcome! :)

Comment: I'll take a pass at fixing it. Thanks again for all your help!